# Calculate image height when width 100% is set

Tags: html

How do you calculate the 'used/determined' height of an image when using `width="100%"`. I need this to determine whether or not to use the `width="100%"` or set a height with a max of `n px`. This is because of images getting to big for their box (div).

I would like to calculate in advance and not to resize the images after they're displayed in the browser. (The scenario is in a product-layout).

Comment: Can you give a working example of your layout in a JSFiddle or similar?

Comment: Do you know before hand the aspect ratio of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the height is the limit, why not use height as the property to adjust the image size as well?

If [this support](http://caniuse.com/minmaxwh) is sufficient, you could use `max-height` and `height`:

```
img {
  height:100%;
  max-height:115px;  
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/JdQK6/

You would set the max-height to the maximum height you'd want the image to be.

Comment: A perfect solution. I've added als the width and max-width to handle landscape images properly. Thank you! +1 and accepted. Maybe CSS should be an abbreviation for Clearly Simple Solution ;)